# Rails ActionController::RoutingError for uploaded assets not present in development machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's very usual for me to clone the production database in my development machine to get development ENV as close to the real thing as possible and to develop/test with real data.

The problem is that, by doing so, many of my views now have references to assets (images) that are user uploaded (CarrierWave), but since we're talking about hundreds of gigs of images it's unpractical to clone these assets as well.

This, however, results in a terrible dev experience: every view that has many of these images results in dozens of requests being handled by the Rails server raising RoutingErrors like this:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/picture/mv_files/image/000/000/051/966/51966/thumb_101__2_.jpg")

In a page with 30+ like these, it takes more then 15 seconds so that Rails server can raise all the exceptions and the next request can be processed.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes after posting this, I found exactly the solution I was looking for in [this excellent Makandra Cards](https://makandracards.com/makandra/45120-rendering-404s-for-missing-images-via-rails-routes):

> Rendering 404s for missing images via Rails routes When you load a
>   dump for development, records may reference images that are not
>   available on your machine.
>
> Requests to those images may end up on your application, e.g. if a
>   catch-all route is defined that leads to a controller doing some heavy
>   lifting. On pages with lots of missing images, this slows down
>   development response times.
>
> You can fix that by defining a Rails route like this:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  scope format: true, constraints: { format: /jpg|png|gif/ } do
    get '/*anything', to: proc { [404, {}, ['']] }
  end
end
```

> Images are (usually) served directly from public or assets and won't hit your
>   controllers/routes, as long as the files exist. If files are missing,
>   the request will be handled by the above route which instantly
>   responds with an empty HTTP 404 response.

So I just pasted that snippet in the beginning of my `routes.rb` file and voilá, problem solved!